# How to remove full stops when counting char's in a string

Tags: c#

I have been set a task of creating a c# console text analysis program. The program allows the user to enter a sentence word by word a single full stop is the end of the sentence a double full stop is to break the loop and give the analysis of the text

I have the program counting words and sentences correctly.

My question is: How can I change my code so that the program will not count full stops as a character?

Below is my code thus far

```
 case "1":

    string UserSentence="";
    string newString="";
    string UserWord;
    int SentenceCount=1;
    int WordCount=0;
    double CharCount=0;

    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to type in your sentance(s) for analysis.\nPlease input each word then press enter.\n\nUse one full stop to end the sentence.\nUse two full stops to finish inputting sentences");
    while (true)
        {
            UserWord = Console.ReadLine();
            WordCount++;
            UserSentence = UserSentence+UserWord;


                if (UserWord == "..")
                    {
                        CharCount=CharCount-2;
                        WordCount--;
                        break;
                    }

                if (UserWord == ".")
                    {
                        CharCount=CharCount-1;
                        WordCount--;
                        SentenceCount++;
                    }
        }

    foreach (char c in UserSentence)

        {
            if (c ==' ')
            continue;
            newString += c;
        }
        CharCount = newString.Length;
        Console.WriteLine("Their are {0} characters",CharCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Their are {0} Sentences",SentenceCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Their are {0} Words",WordCount);
    break;
```

I have tried to correct the character count by subtracting 2 or 1 depending on the amount of full stops however it does not work

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Rather than subtracting from the word count for each full stop as encountered, why not have another variable to tally the full stops? Then subtract this final number at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are simply *overwriting* the value of `CharCount`, discarding all the subtraction you did earlier:

```
CharCount = newString.Length;
```

It can be changed to:

```
CharCount = CharCount + newString.Length;
```

In order to give the correct result.

There are other options, such as counting the number of `.` in the sentence, replacing all the `.` in a sentence in an empty string before getting its length and many more.

Note on style: in C#, local variables are normally camelCase, not PascalCase.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked perfectly. Thanks for the note on style, I always forget the difference and PascalCase looks neater to me so I go with that, however I shall change them before I submit. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to count the characters that aren't spaces or dots.

```
int characterCount = s.Count(x => x != ' ' && x != '.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just count the chars that are not "."

```
CharCount = newString.Where(c => !c.Equals('.') && !c.Equals(' ')).Count();
```